# "ssh: Could not resolve hostname : No address associated with hostname" error with my bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, terminal

I'm trying to make a bash script which connects to openvpn in the terminal, then opens another terminal window and then ssh into a system. But I end up with the error "ssh: Could not resolve hostname : No address associated with hostname". Heres my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo openvpn academy.ovpn & 

gnome-terminal --tab --title="test" --command="bash -c 'read IP; ssh htb-student@$IP; echo HTB_@cademy_stdnt!; $SHELL'"
```

Theres probably some mistake in the "read IP" part or "htb-student@$IP" but I cant figure it out.

I tried surrounding the `$IP` with quotations, but that didn't work. I expect it to ssh without any errors.

Comment: You have double quotes on the outside, so `$IP` is getting expanded before `read IP` even runs at all.

Comment: And what do you mean that `echo` to do? If you want it to be run on the remote machine -- it won't. If you want it to fill in a password prompt, it won't do that either. The way your code is written, the `echo` runs only after ssh exits.

Comment: (In general, you shouldn't be passing passwords around with shell scripts at all in the first place: ssh provides _much_ safer authentication methods; so while tools like `sshpass` exist, it's bad form to use them; you should be setting up key-based authentication instead, ideally with restrictions on usage in the matching `authorized_keys` file, _ideally_ with that key coming from a hardware keystore or otherwise stored in a way that resists duplication).

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you're passing `$IP` inside a double-quoted context, so it's being expanded by the outer shell before `read` ever has a chance to run.

If you want to pass code to a remote shell, have your local shell do the work of encapsulating it by declaring a function and then telling the shell to serialize that function into a string you can pass to ssh:

```
#!/bin/bash

case $BASH_VERSION in [1-4].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 5.0+ needed" >&2; exit 1;; esac

windowedCommand() {
  read IP
  ssh htb-student@"$IP" 'echo "Correctly opened shell $SHELL on remote host; now exiting"'
}

gnome-terminal --tab --title="test" -- \
  bash -c "$(declare -f windowedCommand); windowedCommand"
```